# How to Call Script with Directory

Tags: shell, unix

I have to call one Script in Informatica Command task which is in directory say /home/folder
My script name say scriptName.ksh. Now how can i call it .. 
I am using Command like /home/folder/ ./scriptName.ksh . But it is not working.
cd is put by default.

Comment: your script file must have execution rights..check if it has

Comment: @Alex yes it has, I can run it in that directory. But first i have to go in that cd /home/folder.

Comment: Like: 
    /home/folder/scriptName.ksh

Comment: Please post the first line of your script, the exact command you use to start it, and the exact error message you get. *It is not working* is not an error description which makes it easy for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

the command is wrong
the absolute command to execute your script should be like

```
/home/folder/scriptName.ksh
```